# Main caption by the side of subfigures with subcaptions at the bottom

Tags: captions, subfloats, sidecap

I have 2 subfigures where I need to have the subcaptions underneath each subfigure while the main caption remains on the right hand side.
The code I tried is as follows:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Images/powerQ.png}
    \caption{Quantitative traits}
    \label{fig:a}
\end{subfigure}
\hspace{-0.5cm}
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Images/powerB.png}
    \caption{Binary traits}
    \label{fig:b}
 \end{subfigure}
  \caption{\label{fig:pow} Statistical Power Vs Target Sample Size
  \newline
  {\footnotesize \textit{Heritability was varied as 0.1, 0.2, 0.5 and 0.8 for quantitative traits while fixing the values as 0.1 for binary traits; effective number of chromosome segments was fixed at 50,000; discovery sample size was fixed at 231,034 (80\% of 288,792 of total individuals); number of SNPs was fixed at 1,217,311; population prevalence was varied as 0.05, 0.1, 0.2 and 0.3 for binary traits where it was assumed that the number of cases in both training and validation samples were equal to the corresponding population prevalence values at each instance; the top proportion of genetic scores in the validation sample was fixed at 0.01; significant threshold in power calculation was considered as 0.05}}}
  \label{fig:study3}
 \end{figure}
```

I need to have the main figure caption as shown by the arrow in this attached image:
[image]

Comment: Put the caption in a minipage using up the rest of \textwidth.  Note, you add a `\space` every time you use `\end{subfigure}` instead of `\end{subfigure}%`.

Comment: Posible duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45614/display-the-caption-of-a-figure-as-if-it-was-a-subfigure

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thank you very much, it perfectly worked.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Many thanks for the link shared. Though it seems similar to my issue, I failed to map the exact problem with it. But the top most comment could help instantly.